# How do I force release memory occupied by MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection, idisposable

I have the following code:

```
const int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    const int writesCount = 400;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(writesCount * bufferSize))
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < writesCount; j++)
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

which I run on a 32-bit machine.

The first iteration finishes just fine and then on the next iteration I get a `System.OutOfMemoryException` exception on the line that `new`s the `MemoryStream`.

Why isn't the previous `MemoryStream` memory reclaimed despite `using` statement? How do I force release of memory used by the `MemoryStream`?

Comment: Have you tried forcing the Garbage Collector to run?

Comment: By the way, after writing to the instance of `MemoryStream` you are disposing it **without saving the content of the stream** elsewhere. Why write to the stream if **the stream is un-used after writing**?

Comment: @Serge: This is a snippet to illustrate the problem, that's why.

Comment: Actually you don't have to call `stream.Close()`. The `using` will take call `stream.Dispose()`, which in turn calls the `Close()` already. [click here for further reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274590/memorystream-close-or-memorystream-dispose)

Comment: Use smaller buffers and/or reuse them.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, completely agree with you! One buffer with reusing. Another option is external (file, for example) storage for large pieces of data.

Comment: @sharptooth, in your real code the `writesCount` is also const, isn't it?

Comment: @Serge: Yes, the number of writes is `const` in the real code.

Comment: @Nick: Yes, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: This is a debugger artifact, it extends the lifetime of local variables to the end of the method body.  The using statement adds an extra local variable that also references the stream.  Which causes the code to keep references to two arrays, the previous one and the new one.  The virtual memory address space doesn't have holes big enough for two of these large arrays on a 32-bit OS.  Run in the Release build without a debugger attached or get rid of the *using* statement.  Re-using the buffer is of course best.

Comment: @Hans Passant: If I put the `using` into a separate method and call that method in a loop it still runs out of memory after two iterations. Why isn't GC invoked to gain more memory?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think the problem is the garbage collector not doing its job.  If the GC is under memory pressure it should run and reclaim the 400 MBs you've just allocated.

This is more likely down to the GC not finding a **contigious 400 MB** block.

> Rather, an “out of memory” error happens because the process is unable
> to find a large enough section of *contiguous unused pages in its
> virtual address space to do the requested mapping.*

You should read Eric Lippert's blog entry ["Out Of Memory" Does Not Refer to Physical Memory](https://web.archive.org/web/20100529211435/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx)

You're far better off doing **both** of the below.

1. Reusing the memory block you've allocated (why are you creating another with the exact same size)
2. Allocating much smaller chunks (less than **85KBs**)

Prior to Dotnet 4.5, Dotnet constructed two heaps, **Small Object Heap (SOH)** and **Large Object Heap (LOH)**.  See [Large Object Hearp Improvements in .NET 4.5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/large-object-heap-improvements-in-net-4-5/) by Brandon Bray.  Your `MemoryStream` is being allocated in LOH, and not compacted (defragmented) for the duration of the process, making it much more likely that multiple calls to allocate this large amount of memory will throw an `OutOfMemoryException`

> The CLR manages two different heaps for allocation, the small object
> heap (SOH) and the large object heap (LOH). Any allocation greater
> than or equal to 85,000 bytes goes on the LOH. Copying large objects
> has a performance penalty, so the LOH is not compacted unlike the SOH.
> Another defining characteristic is that the LOH is only collected
> during a generation 2 collection. Together, these have the built-in
> assumption that large object allocations are infrequent.

Comment: +1 Additionally that buffer will be located in LOH, which is never defragmented (in contrast to SOH).

Answer (score 1):

Try to force garbage collection when you are sure that it is necessary to clean unreferenced objects.

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

Another alternative is to use the `Stream` with external storage: `FileStream`, for example.

But, in general case, it would be better to use **one small enough** buffer (array, allocated one time) and use it for read/write calls. Avoid having **many large objects** in .NET (see [CLR Inside Out: Large Object Heap Uncovered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx)).

**Update**

Assuming that the `writesCount` is the constant, the why not allocate one buffer and reuse it?

```
const int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
const int writesCount = 400;

byte[] streamBuffer = new byte[writesCount * bufferSize];
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(streamBuffer))
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < writesCount; j++)
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: isnt dispose supposed to free the memory immediately?

Comment: Disposing does NOT mark memory to be collectable by GC, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359131/memory-release-with-idisposable-and-without-idisposable

Comment: Forcing garbage collection doesn't help.

Comment: @sharptooth, please see the update: the code is just a suggestion.

Comment: How will I get rid of the buffer in the end?

Comment: @sharptooth, byte array will be garbage collected. Again, you can try forcing garbage collection right after the `for` loop. The code I provided allocates **one large buffer**; old code allocates the same large buffer on every loop body execution. Have you tried the code?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're allocating too much than your system can handle. Your code runs fine on my machine, but if I change it like this :

```
const int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 2;
```

I get the same error as you.

But if I change the target processor to x64, then the code runs, which seems logical as you can address lot more memory.

Detailed explanation on this article : http://www.guylangston.net/blog/Article/MaxMemory
And some information on this question : [Maximum Memory a .NET process can allocate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934314/maximum-memory-a-net-process-can-allocate)

Comment: Seems like the underlying issue to me

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Dispose()` does not guarantee that memory will be released (it does not mark objects for GC collection, in case of `MemoryStream` - it releases nothing, as `MemoryStream` has no unmanaged resources). The only reliable way to free memory used by `MemoryStream` is to lose all references to it and wait for garbage collection to occur (and if you have `OutOfMemoryException` - garbage collector already tried but failed to free enough memory). Also, allocating such large objects (anything > 85000 bytes) have some consequences - these objects are going to large object heap (LOH), which can get fragmented (and cannot be compacted). As .NET object must occupy a contiguous sequence of bytes, it can lead to a situation where you have enough memory, but there is no room for large object. Garbage collector won't help in this case.

It seems like the main problem here is that reference to a `stream` object is kept on stack, preventing garbage collection of `stream` object (even forcing garbage collection won't help, as GC considers that object is still alive, you can check this creating a `WeakRefrence` to it). Refactoring this sample can fix it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 2;
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            const int writesCount = 400;
            Write(buffer, writesCount, bufferSize);
        }
    }

    static void Write(byte[] buffer, int writesCount, int bufferSize)
    {
        using(var stream = new MemoryStream(writesCount * bufferSize))
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < writesCount; j++)
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is a sample which proves that object can't be garbage collected:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 2;
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        WeakReference wref = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(wref != null)
            {
                // force garbage collection
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                GC.Collect();
                // check if object is still alive
                Console.WriteLine(wref.IsAlive); // true
            }
            const int writesCount = 400;
            using(var stream = new MemoryStream(writesCount * bufferSize))
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < writesCount; j++)
                {
                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
                // weak reference won't prevent garbage collection
                wref = new WeakReference(stream);
            }
        }
    }
```